# How can i get option accesskey value to js code?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('if-font').innerHTML ='
<a href="http://example.com/?city='**  accesskey  **'"> 
http://example.com/?city='+cityName+'</a>';
```

---

```
    <select name="citySelect" id="citySelect" onchange="selectChanged()" >
        <option selected>Please Select</option>
        <option value="xml/16702.xml" accessKey ="ZZZX">ZZZZ</option>
```

How can i get option accesskey value to js code?

I need to show that link

```
http://example.com/?city=ZZZX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it :)

```
        var selected = document.getElementById("citySelect").value;
        var e = document.getElementById("citySelect");
        sehir = e.options[e.selectedIndex].accessKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var accessKey = document.querySelector('option[value="xml/16702.xml"]')
                               .getAttribute("accessKey");
```

should work fine.

[`element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)